# How can I make Fedora command line mode use the full screen of a big monitor?

Tags: fedora, display, vga

My monitor is 24" and works best at a resolution of 1920x1080.

I use Fedora 15 with the latest NVIDIA driver. In GUI mode, it works perfectly. However in command line mode I have the following issues:

- It doesn't use all of the screen
- There is a big black border
- It only uses 19" of the monitor
- The letters on the screen are quite big

How can I configure it to use the full screen and have a smaller letter size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using Linux virtual consoles in [VGA-compatible text mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VGA_compatible_text_mode), which is limited to a very low resolution (usually 80×25 at 720×400).

You have several choices:

- Use a video driver with support for Kernel Mode Setting. Currently only [Nouveau supports](http://nouveau.freedesktop.org/wiki/KernelModeSetting) it, not the official nVidia driver. On the other hand, KMS works equally for both X11 and consoles, even at the same time, so installing Nouveau might be worth a try.
- Use a framebuffer driver such as `nvidiafb` or `uvesafb` (load using `modprobe`). This <s>may</s>will conflict with the nVidia driver used by X11 – it still works when X11 is *not* running, though.
- Assuming *grub-legacy* as the bootloader, specify a framebuffer mode using the `vga=` boot option – if you can even [find a `vga` value](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB#Framebuffer_resolution) for your native resolution. (Above a certain limit they are non-standard, so you will have to use a detection tool. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VESA_BIOS_Extensions#Linux_video_mode_numbers) does not have an entry for your resolution.)
- Use an X11 terminal emulator. Seriously, just run a full-screen Xterm or something like that.
- Use SVGATextMode, which is *very* old and horribly obsolete.

In KMS/framebuffer modes, you will able to change the font with `setfont` – available fonts might be at /usr/share/kbd/consolefonts/ or /usr/share/console-tools/...

Comment: thanks for detailed answer, but, I found it quite hard for a newbie like me. I will try them when I familiar with linux

Comment: @Freewind: In that case, just sticking with a graphical terminal emulator (GNOME Terminal, Xterm, other) will be the best choice.